# confused on how to pass pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef struct nodeWords
{
    char * word;
    struct nodeWords *left;
    struct nodeWords *right;
} nodeWords;

void leftRightAddress(int buckets, nodeWords *nodeHash);


int main(void)
{
    nodeWords *nodeHash = malloc(500 * sizeof(nodeWords));

    
    leftRightAddress(500, nodeHash);

}

void leftRightAddress(int buckets, nodeWords *nodeHash)
{

}
```

can some explain why when I call the function leftRightAddress() in main I need to use the argument nodeHash and not the pointer *nodeHash?  The function is defined as taking a pointer.

Comment: `int* p` is a pointer to int. You send the name not the type. p is of type `int*`. This is why a function expecting a pointer to an int accepts p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration of nodeHash makes it a pointer type (i.e. points to a location in memory). If you then pass *nodeHash, you are essentially dereferencing it, so what you're actually passing then is the object it is pointing to in memory.

```
nodeWords *nodeHash //nodeHash = pointer to nodeWords object
someFunction(*nodeHash) //passing nodeWords object
someFunction(nodeHash) //passing pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a pointer and getting what it points to is a dereference, and `*nodeHash` is a dereference.

The value of `nodeHash` is a `struct nodeWords *`, i.e. a pointer.

The value of `*nodeHash` is a `struct nodeWords`, i.e. a struct.

The parameter's type is `struct nodeWords *`, so you want to pass the value of `nodeHash` (the pointer), not `*nodeHash` (the struct).